# CSS transition for a div on a IOS safari browser is delayed

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I am using transform: translate() property to faster the css transition in IOS safari browser instead of changing left property as suggested by other answers. But it did not work as expected and it stills lags when changing the position of the DIV. If anyone can point out any fix, it will be great.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score -1):

you can use below code to avoiding error because some browser not understand pure css properly .

```
-ms-transform: translateY ();
-webkit-transform: translateY ();
-moz-transform: translateY ();
-o-transform: translateY ();
transform: translateY();
```